# File is not created on Mac

Tags: java, javafx, terminal, settings

I made program which writes the configuration of the settings to a text file in the directory of the Java executable. The method which writes the file is below.

```
public class ConfigWriter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("MyFile.txt", false);
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(writer);
            bufferedWriter.write(args[0]);
            bufferedWriter.newLine();
            bufferedWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void Config(String[] settings, String[] filenames) {
        System.out.println("Settings: "+Arrays.toString(settings));
        String[] configurations = new String[settings.length+filenames.length];
        int c=0;
        for(int i=0;i<settings.length;i++){
            configurations[i]= settings[i];
            c++;
        }
        for(int j=0;j<filenames.length;j++){
            configurations[c++]= filenames[j];
        }

        try {
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("ConfigFile.txt", false);
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(writer);
            for(int i=0; i<configurations.length; i++){
                bufferedWriter.write(configurations[i]);
                bufferedWriter.newLine();
            }
            bufferedWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

When this method is called it typically writes a file named Config.txt file to the directory where the executable is.

However, while this seems to work for the Windows version of the App. the Mac version of the app seems to be having some issues with the latest update of the MACOS. This Config.txt file can be created from on MAC but I need to run the Java executable from the command line. Any thoughts as to why the Config.txt file is created when running the Java executable from the command line but not when click on it as an app?

I have attached the script where Config method is called below:

```
 button.setOnAction( e -> {
                //System.out.println("Running Proteinarium");
                //System.out.println(ProjectName.getText());

                if(ProjectName.getText() != null){
                    Projectname = ProjectName.getText();
                }

                if(GS1FileLocation!=null && GS2FileLocation!=null){
                    filenames = new String[]{GS1FileLocation, GS2FileLocation, "projectName="+Projectname};
                    ConfigWriter.Config(Settingsarray, filenames);
                    final ProteinariumThread service = new ProteinariumThread();
                    service.start();
                    window.setScene(scene2);
                    textArea.appendText("Proteinarium Running see " + fileName+ " for additional information on the Proteinarium Run... \n");
                }
                else if(GS1FileLocation!=null){
                    filenames = new String[]{GS1FileLocation,"projectName="+Projectname};
                    ConfigWriter.Config(Settingsarray, filenames);
                    final ProteinariumThread service = new ProteinariumThread();
                    service.start();
                    window.setScene(scene2);
                    textArea.appendText("Proteinarium Running see " + fileName+ " for additional information on the Proteinarium Run... \n");
                }
                else if(GS2FileLocation!=null){
                    filenames = new String[]{GS2FileLocation,"projectName="+Projectname};
                    ConfigWriter.Config(Settingsarray, filenames);
                    final ProteinariumThread service = new ProteinariumThread();
                    service.start();
                    window.setScene(scene2);
                    textArea.appendText("Proteinarium Running see " + fileName+ " for additional information on the Proteinarium Run... \n");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("No Genesetfile recorded");
                    Alert dg = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
                    dg.setTitle("Proteinarium Information");
                    dg.setContentText("Please Specify a Geneset File");
                    dg.show();
                }

    }
    );
```

Comment: If you’re going to work with files, it is a good idea to learn what a [current directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) is.  A filename with no directory component is relative to the current directory, which is not reliable.  A known directory like the user’s home directory is more reliable:  `new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "MyFile.txt")`

Answer (score -1):

Maybe instead of

```
new FileWriter("MyFile.txt", false);
```

try

```
new FileWriter(new File("MyFile.txt").getAbsolutePath(), false);
```

I'm not sure if that will fix the issue, but it might be a path problem